# Cyrillic routes

Tags: cakephp, routes, cyrillic

I am trying to set up a cakephp Route rule like:

```
Router::connect(
        '/:language/:site',
        array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'),
        array(
            'language' => $langs,
            'site' => $siteTitles
        )
);
```

Where $langs looks like: en|de|ru
and $siteTitles looks like: metal|metall|металл

This works fine for latin languages but with the Cyrillic version (металл) i'm getting an "Error: металлController could not be found."

Looks like the regex is not understanding the russian version.

I'm running my app with UTF-8 coding.

Comment: Problem solved!

Should have seen that coming:
A simple urlencode on the strings will do.

Comment: Answer your question and mark it as correct answer so it could finally benefit someone who sees it ;) welcome to stack!

Comment: Lional, Thanx for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Should have seen that coming:
A simple urlencode on the strings will do.